# Laravel 5.6 - Get First Key from DB JSON Value

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5.6

In DB I have saved value like this:

`["IMG_4772.JPG","IMG_4775.JPG"]`

In my view I'm trying to get first key like this:

`background-image: url( {{ asset('img/ads/' . json_decode($ad->images, true)[0]) }} );`

While inspecting element URL looks perfectly, as needed - `/public/img/ads/IMG_4772.JPG`. I'm also able to copy/paste/open this URL in my browser and see the pic.

But the console gives me an error `GET /public/img/ads/IMG_4772.JPG 0 ()` and the pic is not displayed as background-image of the block. What is the problem?

Controller:

```
if ( $request->hasfile('images') ) {
    foreach ( $request->file('images' ) as $image) {
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(public_path() . '/img/ads/', $name);
        $data[] = $name;
    }
}

$ad->images = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: @MehravishTemkar the site is not accessible at all without writing /public/ . I'm using Laragon as local server.

Comment: Ohh my bad sorry

Comment: Are you using localhost?

Comment: @ChinLeung yes, it's at local machine. I believe something is wrong with my public storage...

Answer (score 0):

try add slashes

```
background-image: url('{{ asset('img/ads/' . json_decode($ad->images, true)[0]) }}');
```